# GWT doesn't upload a file

Tags: java, html, http, gwt, servlets

Here's my code to let the user upload a file and save it for future reference.
The entry point class-Home.java has the following --

```
FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
FormPanel fp = new FormPanel();
fp.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
fp.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
fp.setAction("\\UploadServlet");
upload.setName("file-upload");
```

Alongwith the necessary additional code for adding in the RootPanel and all.

Q1. Should something like

```
fp.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"UploadServlet");
```

be preferred for setAction? and what path exactly should be put in here?

The UploadServlet class has been taken from

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm
with

```
String filePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload");
```

Also the web.xml file has

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.gwt.dlogpackage.client.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Q2. Now I dont know why this doesn't work. It doesn't get any fileitems in UploadServlet class. When I use the HTML code for the same it works but it doesn't by this java code. Can someone tell me why?

Q3. Also is something like this in web.xml necessary?

```
<context-param> 
    <description>Location to store uploaded file</description> 
    <param-name>file-upload</param-name> 
    <param-value> C:\users\.. </param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors when it doesn't upload?

Answer (score 0):

See how it looks your module gwt.xml :

```
<module rename-to='module_name'>
...
</module>
```

Method GWT.getModuleBaseURL() return String: "module_name".
So if you type :

```
fp.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"UploadServlet");
```

the result is :

```
fp.setAction("module_name/UploadServlet");
```

So web.xml should look like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.gwt.dlogpackage.client.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>module_name/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: In UploadServlet class, it has statements -- DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(); ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory); List<FileItem> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request); Iterator<FileItem> i = fileItems.iterator(); while (i.hasNext()) FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next(); (But it never enters this while statement. why so??)

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

I do think that

```
fp.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"UploadServlet");
```

is better

**Q2**

In my experience, most of the issues I've had with the file not uploading is that the `FormPanel` needs to be attached to the page for the entire length of the upload.

If you're removing the `FormPanel` after/during the upload try leaving it until you get the callback. So something like:

```
FormPanel panel = new FormPanel();
...
panel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler(){

    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event){
        // Keep FormPanel visible until this method is called
    }

}):
```

**Q3**

I assume that you need your web.xml to be like that given how your server works but you can easily have another implementation without that `<param-value>...</param-value>` tag.

Comment: In UploadServlet class, it has statements --       DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);    
List<FileItem> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);     
Iterator<FileItem> i = fileItems.iterator();      
while (i.hasNext())                                           FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next();      (But it never enters this while statement. why so??)

Comment: Did you try debugging? Is the servlet even being called? What code in the servlet's being run?

Comment: UploadServlet is being called but fileItem's size is 0 so maybe upload.parseRequest(request) isn't returning anything. Why so??

Answer (score 0):

If you have your upload-file servlet declared like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.gwt.dlogpackage.client.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you shoud code:

```
fp.setAction("UploadServlet");
```

I mean, without the forward slash delimiter at the beggining of the action name. This is because you are already stepped on the root of your context, so you must invoke your form action without  referring to the root (sorry if I express myself badly).

May I add just a suggestion: If I were you I would name the fileUploader with the same as the form action name.

Finally, as enyrbo has said, attach the FormPanel to the page (I assume you have coded your onSubmit and onSubmitComplete handlers).

Comment: In UploadServlet class, it has statements -- DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(); ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory); List<FileItem> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request); Iterator<FileItem> i = fileItems.iterator(); while (i.hasNext()) FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next(); (But it never enters this while statement. why so??)

Comment: There is no need to use iterator pattern, you can use a for each statement throught the fileItems like this: for (FileItem fileItem: fileItems) { ... }. Just to keep this in mind, add this LOC to your while: if (item.isFormField()) continue; that is because you need file fields not just anything.

Comment: I suggest you debugging your code and put a breakpoint in the request parameter, maybe there is something missing there, like the path to the file in your FS.

Comment: upload.parseRequest(request) isn't returning anything I guess, because fileItems's size is 0.